# xlsx excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid - c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an excel file from the response of SSRS reporting server, on front-end I successfully able to download an excel file but when I open it I get the error.

> xlsx excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Here is the code:

```
  HttpWebRequest req =
                  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sTargetURL);
            req.PreAuthenticate = true;
            req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strReportUser, strReportUserPW, strReportUserDomain);
            HttpWebResponse HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream fStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();

            //Now turn around and send this as the response..
            byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(fStream);

            string fileToAttach = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            HttpWResp.Close();

            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            result.Content = fileToAttach;
            result.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
 officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            result.FileName = fileName + ".xlsx";
            result.result = true;
            return result;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type is `result`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `response` is some kind of HTTP response object that eventually gets sent to the browser, and that you have the actual Excel file contents in `fStream`, the problem is you are sending the Base64'd version of the file as the contents (which Excel is not going to understand):

```
        Stream fStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(fStream);
        string fileToAttach = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
        result.Content = fileToAttach;
```

---

Since I can't see what `response` is, all I can say is you need to leave the file contents intact.

If you want to send the raw bytes, you could do:

```
        Stream fStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(fStream);
        result.Content = fileBytes;
```

If your `response` can handle a Stream, that would be the ideal way (then you don't have to convert it back and forth between a stream and byte data).

If `result.Content` *has* to be a string, then you have to worry about which encoding to use, and it'll look something like:

```
        Stream fStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(fStream);
        result.Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);
```

It wouldn't surprise me if Excel needs to be encoded as UTF-16 ([Microsoft uses it quite heavily internally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows)).